# Wordpress Customizer: custom redirection after closing

Tags: redirect

Someone knows if is there a way to customize the redirection after a user click "close" in the Wordpress Customizer" live editor?

It would be very useful.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try to use *jQuery* to change the url behind the *Close* link.

Another idea would be to use `wp_get_referer()` to intercept the page loading when you go from `customize.php` to `themes.php` by hooking into the `load-themes.php` action:

```
add_action( 'load-themes.php', 'my_customize_redirect' );
function my_customize_redirect() {

    if ( strstr( wp_get_referer(), '/wp-admin/customize.php' ) )
    {
            $url = get_admin_url(); // EDIT this to your needs
            wp_safe_redirect( $url );
            exit();
    }

}
```

Comment: [Here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/116263/26350) is a jQuery solution.

Comment: I filed a Core track ticket [#25457 here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25457). My user-experience is that the Theme Customizer feels like a fullscreen popup with a close button. 
When I close it, I expect to go back to the previous page.