# Redirect after closing Theme Customizer when user does not have permission for theme page

Tags: redirect, permissions, theme-customizer

I'm looking for a way to alter the href target for the "close" button from the theme customizer.  Another question/answer came very close, but in my case the solution used which involved "load-themes.php" doesn't work because the user in question wouldn't have permission to access that page.  ( [Wordpress Customizer: custom redirection after closing](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115731/wordpress-customizer-custom-redirection-after-closing) )

Basically the "Close" button now takes the user to a page that tells them they don't have permission to access it.  I'd like it to redirect to the main admin page but I'm not sure how to do that.  The other solution mentioned using jQuery, but I have NO clue how to do that.  I tried messing around with it for a while but I really have no idea what I'm doing at this point.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this *jQuery* script injected via the `customize_controls_print_footer_scripts` hook:

```
/**
 * Change the url of the Close link in the /wp-admin/customize.php page
 * See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/116257
 */
function change_close_url_wpse_116257() {
    $url = get_admin_url(); // Edit this to your needs
    printf( "<script>
                jQuery(document).ready( function(){ 
                    jQuery('#customize-header-actions a.back.button').attr('href', '%s'); 
                });
            </script>"
            , esc_js( $url ) );     
}
add_action( 'customize_controls_print_footer_scripts', 'change_close_url_wpse_116257' );
```

Comment: I filed a Core track ticket [#25457 here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25457). My user-experience is that the Theme Customizer feels like a fullscreen popup with a close button. 
When I close it, I expect to go back to the previous page.